# Small utility to use a LAN chat in my WiFi connection using Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, lan, chat

My brother is in the next hotel room and no wifi is here... For fun we'd like to use ad hoc wifi connection and a small utility to do a little chat... Is it possible?

Do you have any utility suggestion?

Net send is gone in windows 7 and msg doesn't look friendly.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [RealPopup](http://download.cnet.com/3001-2085_4-10019886.html?spi=60639c0d99ce49d546fdb5fcbe801350)

[image]